# Replacing content between section breaks

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I need to process a huge amount of word documents in order to replace the content of the document between 2 section breaks.

Basically the document is structured like the following :

```
Content    
========= Continuous Section Break ==========
Content with 2 columns
========= Continuous Section Break ==========
Content
```

I already know how to detect the breaks in the document

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true)) 

{ 

MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart; 

List<Break> breaks = mainPart.Document.Descendants<Break>().ToList(); 

// TODO replace content between the breaks 

mainPart.Document.Save(); 

}
```

But I don't know how to replace the content between them.

Any Help appreciated.

Comment: In MS Word you will find `Sections collection` which allows to manipulate with each of them separately. `Sections` have `.Range property` which refers to text range. Try with these tips.

Comment: @KazJaw Thanks, but I'm using Open XML SDK, not VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the OpenXML Power Tools as explained in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/05/move-insert-delete-paragraphs-in-word-processing-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx).